# Установка devdocs

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby

Как установить на локахост https://github.com/Thibaut/devdocs ?
После выполнения команды bundle install консоль ругается на отсутствие gemfile.

Comment: Выполняете команду в директории devdocs?

Answer (score 0):

Команда `bundle install` устанавливает гемы, указанные в Gemfile, который расположен в директории, из которой эта команда вызывается.
Перейдите в директорию devdocs:

`cd devdocs_path`

где **devdocs_path** - путь к директории devdocs и запустите

`bundle install`